# Lucene - How to discard numeric terms in indexing?

Tags: lucene, analyzer

Using [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/index.html), my Lucene contain numeric terms too(i.e. "200"). So number of term in my index is too big.
Does anyone know if exists an Analyzer or Tokenizer that discards numeric terms?
If not, is there any easy way to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antonio, I suggest you try using [SimpleAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/SimpleAnalyzer.html).

If this does not work for you, you may have to write your own analyzer.